# Option to execute my Cordova Mobile App in System context menu

Tags: cordova, contextmenu, windows-phone-8

I have a Cordova(PhoneGap) WindowsPhone8 mobile app that stores URL's on a remote server.

These URL's can be anywhere on the phone, in an email, in the SMS inbox, or even in another app.

Is it possible to add to the system's context menu an option to execute my app on selected/or long pressed URL's

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the tap event or other required events to handle this.

A simple implementation for this can be done using the plugin http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/